# 404 fail with pytest when 'manage.py shell' and browser don't

Tags: python, django, http-status-code-404, pytest

I want to use pytest to test a web app I'm working on. I'm starting small:

```
def test_loading_page(client):
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert b'Congratulations on your first Django' in response.content
```

According to the output of pytest, this looks to be working as intended:

```
platform win32 -- Python 3.6.1, pytest-3.0.7, py-1.4.33, pluggy-0.4.0
Django settings: test_project.settings (from ini file)
rootdir: C:\--\---\---\---\---\---, inifile: pytest.ini
plugins: django-3.1.2
collected 1 items

test_project.py F

================================== FAILURES ===================================
______________________________ test_loading_page _______________________________

client = <django.test.client.Client object at 0x000002440F0A17F0>

    def test_loading_page(client):
        response = client.get('/')
>       assert response.status_code == 200
E       assert 404 == 200
E        +  where 404 = <HttpResponseNotFound status_code=404, "text/html">.status_code

test_test_project.py:7: AssertionError
========================== 1 failed in 0.36 seconds ===========================
```

So while the django dev server is running, test_loading_page fails because of the 404. If use my browser to go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ the loading page is displayed. Also if I use the python manage.py shell, the following code runs correctly:

```
from django.test import Client
client = Client()
response =  client.get('/')
response.status_code == 200 #Returns True
```

In case it's useful, the pytest.ini file contains:

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = flawlesslinguistics.settings
```

And the urls.py file is as default:

from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Versions I'm using are:

***Python 3.6.1***

***pytest-3.0.7***

***django-3.1.2***

It's difficult to identify which articles/docs are referring to pytest and which are for django's built in testing framework using unittest. Any help from an expert would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your urls.py?

Comment: Added to the question noes1s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if this:

```
def test_loading_page(client):
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert b'Congratulations on your first Django' in response.content
```

is your views.py Then you have not mapped this view through to the urls.py

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^test_loading_page/$', views.test_loading_page),
]
```

Depending on the total setup of your app, whether you have multiple urls.py one in mainproject and one in myapp. You may need to 'include' and map the urls through.

Comment: Yeah I followed your clue when asking about urls.py and came to the same conclusion. As placeholder content appears on screen when no view is actually set up I imagined it would be testabel through pytest in the same way as a developed view. I'll accept your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

I think Pytest and Django need some help to work together. Check out the [pytest-django](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) plugin to make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the questions from noes1s, I investigated the urls.py chain.

I added a placeholder view in a project app and wired them up with the following changes:

**Test_project_urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^test_project_app/', include('test_project_app.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**Test_project_app_urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

**Test_project_app_views.py**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Congratulations on your first Django")
```

So with these changes pytest worked as expected. It seems the problem here was that the typical default django page is not accessible in the same way a custom view is when created and hooked up with the urls.py files.

Note the initial test needed altered slightly to work as intended:

```
def test_loading_page(client):
    response = client.get('/test_project_app/')
    assert response.status_code == 200
    assert 'Congratulations on your first Django' in str(response.content)
```